Generate Path3d procedurally and avoid it intersecting with PhysicsBody
Godot Version
4.3
Question
how to generate Path-3d procedurally and avoid it intersecting with PhysicsBody3D. This 3d-path will connect two StaticBody3D. The start and end points of Path3D point normal to the face of StaticBody3D.

Note: I want to create a system that generates wire using CSGMesh and Path3D to connect electrical components. Maybe there are other alternative ways I can do it.
example in unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2g3mIr8M2s

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like the Navigation system has what you are looking for: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_navigationserver3d.html#class-navigationserver3d-method-map-get-path

You may be interested in this thread and the linked papers on repulsive curves and surfaces
